# Get instance of dgrid byId

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

How do I get the reference to the JavaScript object representing a dgrid instance. Consider this code:

```
var MyGrid = var EntityList = declare("ui.MyGrid", [List, Pagination], { ... });
var grid = new MyGrid();
domConstruct.place(grid.domNode, container);
grid.startup();
```

It's easy enough to access `grid` here because it's created programmatically, but if it's created declaratively, as in:

```
<div id="grid" data-dojo-type="ui.MyGrid" data-dojo-props="...">
```

- `dojo.byId('grid')` returns the DOM node.
- `dijit.byId('grid')` returns `undefined`.
- adding `data-dojo-id` apparently has no effect.

How do I get a reference to the the actual javascript object behind `#grid`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your grid needs to mixin the `dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry` extension.  Grids with this extension will register themselves with the dijit registry so you can use `dijit.byId('grid')`.

See https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/DijitRegistry for more information.